# Docs for Parse Server Query Builder

Tags: parse-server

Sorry for a newbie question which I'd ask anyway.

I am relatively new to Parse server and the eco-system. I am unable to find any comprehensive documentation for`Parse-Server Query Builder`. Can anyone refer me to the documentations of Parse-Server Query builder? The documentation [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/) is so incomplete for querying data on the parse server. It does not answer all of my questions.

**P.S:** I am using mongodb for database.

Answer (score 1):

luckily parse-server providers SDK's for all common programming languages like: iOS, Android, JavaScript, PHP and many more. 
In each one of this SDK's you can perform all CRUD operations very easily. Of course that you can also create queries and execute them against your parse-server instance.

You can find all SDK's in here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/

An example of how to execute queries in iOS can be found here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#queries

for Android in here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#queries

for JavaScript/Node.js in here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#queries

I recommend you also to read the getting started section ahead in order to understand how to setup the SDK for the specific client that you are working on.

Good luck!

Comment: Appreciate it, but I was looking for API documentation. I am really bad at picking things quickly. 
here is what I was looking for http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Query.html